# Why can't I assign people to have jobs?

Tags: kingdom-two-crowns

When I give people at camps coins to grab bows and hammers etc. they just stand around instead of taking jobs. How do I fix this?

Comment: You're giving the villagers coins? Just to be sure, because you're phrasing it a bit vague: you know you should buy the bows and hammers, right? They will appear in front of the stalls, for the villagers to pick up.

Comment: I'm giving the people in camps with black ripped clothes coins so that they will pick up the bows and hammers that i bought... most if them work like normal, but a small group of them with no jobs to the right refuse to pick up tools.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: not really... just picture lots of villagers who aren't picking up hammers or bows.